# how to override a jquery script

Tags: jquery

I have an script which runs once the page is loaded

```
$("#node-title").html("Node 0");
```

I want to create an event (clicking on a button) which will change the the node title innerHtml

```
$( "button#new-child" ).click(function () {
...
$("#node-title").html("Node " + counter);
});
```

where counter is defined in the code.

This doesn't work, and I think its because I can't override the first script. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not "overriding" any script. It simply replaces value in the DOM. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Do you have a <node-title>- tag in your markup? Im guessing not. If node-title is a class, selector is $(".node-title"), if id $("#node-title")

Comment: Oops, I forgot the # sign. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the code above. Any more ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `counter` is actually defined in that scope? Otherwise the code should work.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? It may bye related to how your markup is laid out or how your jQuery is structured.

Comment: OK, I figured it out and it works fine. I just had multiple buttons defined and I was clicking on the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct markup, it should work. Have a look at the HTML and JavaScript in this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/utucej/1/edit